# Split numerical count in Spark DataFrame column into several columns

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

Let's say I have a spark DataFrame like this

```
+------------------+----------+--------------+-----+
|              user|        dt|        action|count|
+------------------+----------+--------------+-----+
|Albert            |2018-03-24|Action1       |   19|
|Albert            |2018-03-25|Action1       |    1|
|Albert            |2018-03-26|Action1       |    6|
|Barack            |2018-03-26|Action2       |    3|
|Barack            |2018-03-26|Action3       |    1|
|Donald            |2018-03-26|Action3       |   29|
|Hillary           |2018-03-24|Action1       |    4|
|Hillary           |2018-03-26|Action2       |    2|
```

and I'd like to have counts for Action1/Action2/Action3 in the separate counts, so to convert it into another DataFrame like this

```
+------------------+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|              user|        dt|action1_count|action2_count|action3_count|
+------------------+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|Albert            |2018-03-24|           19|            0|            0|
|Albert            |2018-03-25|            1|            0|            0|
|Albert            |2018-03-26|            6|            0|            0|
|Barack            |2018-03-26|            0|            3|            0|
|Barack            |2018-03-26|            0|            0|            1|
|Donald            |2018-03-26|            0|            0|           29|
|Hillary           |2018-03-24|            4|            0|            0|
|Hillary           |2018-03-26|            0|            2|            0|
```

As I'm a newbie to Spark, my attempt to reach that was quite dull and straightforward:

- Get 3 new DF's from filtering by each "action"
- Join original DF with each of new ones, using the second DF's "count" in the new DF

The code I tried looked like this:

```
val a1 = originalDf.filter("action = 'Action1'")
val df1 = originalDf.as('o)
  .join(a1,
        ($"o.user" === $"a1.user" && $"o.dt" === $"a1.dt"), 
        "left_outer")
  .select($"o.user", $"o.dt", $"a1.count".as("action1_count"))
```

Then do the same with Action2/Action3, then join those.

However, even at this stage I've already got several problems with such approach:

1. It doesn't work at all - I mean fails with an error the reason of which I don't understand: `org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'o.user' given input columns: [user, dt, action, count, user, dt, action, count];`
2. Even if it succeeded, I assume I would have got nulls where I need zeros.
3. I feel there should be a better way to reach this. Like some map construct or something. But at the moment I don't feel I'm able to construct the transform required to convert first dataframe into second one.

So as right now I don't have working solution at all, I'll be very thankful for any suggestions.

**UPD**: I might also get DF's that don't contain all of 3 possible "action" values, for instance

```
+------------------+----------+--------------+-----+
|              user|        dt|        action|count|
+------------------+----------+--------------+-----+
|Albert            |2018-03-24|Action1       |   19|
|Albert            |2018-03-25|Action1       |    1|
|Albert            |2018-03-26|Action1       |    6|
|Hillary           |2018-03-24|Action1       |    4|
```

For those, I still need the resulting DF with 3 columns:

```
+------------------+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|              user|        dt|action1_count|action2_count|action3_count|
+------------------+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|Albert            |2018-03-24|           19|            0|            0|
|Albert            |2018-03-25|            1|            0|            0|
|Albert            |2018-03-26|            6|            0|            0|
|Hillary           |2018-03-24|            4|            0|            0|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid multiple `join` by using `when` to select appropriate value of column.
About your `join`, I don't really think it got exception like `cannot resolve 'o.user'`, you may want to check your code again.

```
val df = Seq(("Albert","2018-03-24","Action1",19),
("Albert","2018-03-25","Action1",1),
("Albert","2018-03-26","Action1",6),
("Barack","2018-03-26","Action2",3),
("Barack","2018-03-26","Action3",1),
("Donald","2018-03-26","Action3",29),
("Hillary","2018-03-24","Action1",4),
("Hillary","2018-03-26","Action2",2)).toDF("user", "dt", "action", "count")

val df2 = df.withColumn("count1", when($"action" === "Action1", $"count").otherwise(lit(0))).
withColumn("count2", when($"action" === "Action2", $"count").otherwise(lit(0))).
withColumn("count3", when($"action" === "Action3", $"count").otherwise(lit(0)))

+-------+----------+-------+-----+------+------+------+
|user   |dt        |action |count|count1|count2|count3|
+-------+----------+-------+-----+------+------+------+
|Albert |2018-03-24|Action1|19   |19    |0     |0     |
|Albert |2018-03-25|Action1|1    |1     |0     |0     |
|Albert |2018-03-26|Action1|6    |6     |0     |0     |
|Barack |2018-03-26|Action2|3    |0     |3     |0     |
|Barack |2018-03-26|Action3|1    |0     |0     |1     |
|Donald |2018-03-26|Action3|29   |0     |0     |29    |
|Hillary|2018-03-24|Action1|4    |4     |0     |0     |
|Hillary|2018-03-26|Action2|2    |0     |2     |0     |
+-------+----------+-------+-----+------+------+------+
```

Comment: Cool, I didn't know about `when` function, so thanks for suggestion! This solution seems to fit my current needs, so I'll accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach using `pivot` and `first`, with the advantage of not having to know what the `action` values are:

```
val df = Seq(
  ("Albert", "2018-03-24", "Action1", 19),
  ("Albert", "2018-03-25", "Action1", 1),
  ("Albert", "2018-03-26", "Action1", 6),
  ("Barack", "2018-03-26", "Action2", 3),
  ("Barack", "2018-03-26", "Action3", 1),
  ("Donald", "2018-03-26", "Action3", 29),
  ("Hillary", "2018-03-24", "Action1", 4),
  ("Hillary", "2018-03-26", "Action2", 2)
).toDF("user", "dt", "action", "count")

val pivotDF = df.groupBy("user", "dt", "action").pivot("action").agg(first($"count")).
  na.fill(0).
  orderBy("user", "dt", "action")

// +-------+----------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
// |   user|        dt| action|Action1|Action2|Action3|
// +-------+----------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
// | Albert|2018-03-24|Action1|     19|      0|      0|
// | Albert|2018-03-25|Action1|      1|      0|      0|
// | Albert|2018-03-26|Action1|      6|      0|      0|
// | Barack|2018-03-26|Action2|      0|      3|      0|
// | Barack|2018-03-26|Action3|      0|      0|      1|
// | Donald|2018-03-26|Action3|      0|      0|     29|
// |Hillary|2018-03-24|Action1|      4|      0|      0|
// |Hillary|2018-03-26|Action2|      0|      2|      0|
// +-------+----------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

[UPDATE]

Per comments, if you have more `Action?` to be created as columns than those in the pivot column, you can traverse the *missing* `Action?` to add them as zero-filled as columns:

```
val fullActionList = List("Action1", "Action2", "Action3", "Action4", "Action5")

val missingActions = fullActionList.diff(
  pivotDF.select($"action").as[String].collect.toList.distinct
)
// missingActions: List[String] = List(Action4, Action5)

missingActions.foldLeft( pivotDF )( _.withColumn(_, lit(0)) ).
show

// +-------+----------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
// |   user|        dt| action|Action1|Action2|Action3|Action4|Action5|
// +-------+----------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
// | Albert|2018-03-24|Action1|     19|      0|      0|      0|      0|
// | Albert|2018-03-25|Action1|      1|      0|      0|      0|      0|
// | Albert|2018-03-26|Action1|      6|      0|      0|      0|      0|
// | Barack|2018-03-26|Action2|      0|      3|      0|      0|      0|
// | Barack|2018-03-26|Action3|      0|      0|      1|      0|      0|
// | Donald|2018-03-26|Action3|      0|      0|     29|      0|      0|
// |Hillary|2018-03-24|Action1|      4|      0|      0|      0|      0|
// |Hillary|2018-03-26|Action2|      0|      2|      0|      0|      0|
// +-------+----------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've got One extra question, though: what if I have another DF which will contain only Action1? Is there a way to ensure I will always have all of "Action1"/"Action2"/"Action3" columns?

Comment: `pivot` transforms distinct values of the pivot column into individual columns, so if there is only value `Action1`, it'll be the only column generated – although in that case since all the other `Action?` columns should be zeros, you can easily add them using `withColumn`.

Comment: That's true, I can add the missing `Action?` using `withColumn`. The issue is, I don't know the contents of my DF a-priori, so it seems as if I would need to implement `pivot` + "if there is no `Action1` in column `action`, then apply extra `withColumn` "

Comment: As long as you have the full `action` list you want to generate as columns, you can programmatically do it.  Please see my expanded answer.